# Is Tor image friendly?

Tags: virtual-machine, private-key, virtualisation

Are there any security concerns if multiple copies of a *single* Tor installation are used simultaneously? I ask this question in the context of virtual machine images or containers.

Worded differently, does Tor generate secret information that should not be made public upon installation or first run? (like openssh)

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but be aware that using tor or other similar software on a virtual machine is as secure as the lower level "real machine" so it might not be a great idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not a relay and if you're not hosting a hidden service, then you can run multiple instances with exactly the same config.

If you are running a hidden service, then each introduction point will use the one that it heard about last. All instances should function though.

If you are running a relay, then each instance must have its own unique keys and fingerprint.